# R Converting Data Frame from Long to Wide

Tags: r, formatting

I'm trying to convert a data frame from long to wide format, but I'm running into the same issue - I get NA's.  I think there might be something wrong with the aggregate function I'm using:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

ID_NUMERIC <- c(5525,5525,5525,5525,5525,8523,8523,8523,8523,8523,4569,4569,4569,4569,4569)
SAMPLE_NAME <-c("HX44","HX44","HX44","HX44","HX44","RT5","RT5","RT5","RT5","RT5","OP1","OP1","OP1","OP1","OP1")
DATE <- c(as.Date("1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014"))
ANALYSIS<- c("P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8")
COMPONENT_NAME <- c("Density","Gravity","C6","C7","C8","Density","Gravity","C6","C7","C8","Density","Gravity","C6","C7","C8")
RESULT <- c(0.8593,33.13,2.1,2.3,2.2,0.8593,33.13,2.1,2.3,2.2,0.8593,33.13,2.1,2.3,2.2)
NAME <- c("HX","HX","HX","HX","HX","RT","RT","RT","RT","RT","OP","OP","OP","OP","OP")

first <- data.frame(ID_NUMERIC,SAMPLE_NAME,DATE,COMPONENT_NAME,ANALYSIS,RESULT,NAME)

second <- ddply(first, .(COMPONENT_NAME), function(x){x$id=1:nrow(x);x})
last <- dcast(second, NAME+SAMPLE_NAME+DATE+ID_NUMERIC+ANALYSIS+id~COMPONENT_NAME, value.var="RESULT")
```

Comment: what happened to all the quotation marks on the character vector elements? Also, should the `HX44`'s be comma-separated?

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks.  I originally got the dataframe from an SQL query, but wanted to make a reproducible example and forgot the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You could put the data into a matrix and work with it from there?

```
ID_NUMERIC <- c(5525,5525,5525,5525,5525,8523,8523,8523,8523,8523,4569,4569,4569,4569,4569)
SAMPLE_NAME <-c("HX44","HX44","HX44","HX44","HX44","RT5","RT5","RT5","RT5","RT5","OP1","OP1","OP1","OP1","OP1")
COMPONENT_NAME<-c("Density","Gravity","C6","C7","C8","Density","Gravity","C6","C7","C8","Density","Gravity","C6","C7","C8")
NAME<-c("HX","HX","HX","HX","HX","RT","RT","RT","RT","RT","OP","OP","OP","OP","OP")
ANALYSIS<-c("P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8","P8")
DATE <- c("1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/15/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014")
RESULT <- c(0.8593,33.13,2.1,2.3,2.2,0.8593,33.13,2.1,2.3,2.2,0.8593,33.13,2.1,2.3,2.2)
data<-matrix(c(ID_NUMERIC,SAMPLE_NAME,DATE,ANALYSIS,COMPONENT_NAME,RESULT,NAME),nrow=7,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(data)<-c("ID_NUMERIC","SAMPLE_NAME","DATE","ANALYSIS","COMPONANT_NAME","RESULT","NAME")
View(data)
data.frame(data)
```

Comment: data is originally coming from an sql query. just created the df as an example to show how the data looks like

Comment: ok. but you saif you wanted it wide instead of long right? this creates a wide dataframe instead of a long one

Comment: Right...but the structure of the SQL database is long, so when I make the query it's long

Comment: im slightly confused...are you wanting your data to be a wide dataframe (like having the data in rows instead of columns) or was that just something for this data set?